# How to avoid writing code with similar structure in my case?

Tags: scala

This is **NOT** a broad question.

I'm using Akka + Spray for a small project. However, I notice that I keep writing code with similar structure and they all bear similarities, for examples, some blocks look like this:

```
 val response = (secCompanyActor ? WebGetOneCompany)
                 .mapTo[TransOk]
                .map(result => result.succeedOrNot match {
                case true => (OK, result.company.get)
                case false => (BadRequest, result.errorMessage)
              })
              complete(response)
```

The other block looks like this: (the only difference is `TransAllOk` instead of `TransOK`)

```
val response = (secCompanyActor ? CasperGetAllCompanies)
            .mapTo[TransAllOk].map(result => result.succeedOrNot match {
              case true => (OK, result.companies.get)
              case false => (BadRequest, result.errorMessage)
            }).recover { case _ => (BadRequest, "An error has occurred! We will fix this")}
            complete(response)
```

The signature of `TransOK` and `TransAllOK` is here:

```
  case class TransOk(company: Option[Company.Company], errorMessage: Option[String])
  case class TransAllOk(companies: Option[List[Company.Company]], errorMessage: Option[String])
```

Sometimes, there are some simple get->return database queries in my program that look very similar:

```
case Register =>
  val result = DAL.db.withSession{ implicit session =>
    MTurker.insert()
  }
  sender ! TransOk(result._1, result._2, result._3)
```

And the next one calls a different method on a different object but the structure is the same:

```
case WebGetOneCompany =>
  val result = DAL.db.withSession{ implicit session =>
    Company.getOneCompany()
  }
  sender ! TransOk(result._1, result._2, result._3)
```

Both `Company` and `MTurker` is an object.

What type of knowledge can help me write more concise code that deals with my current problem? Generics?

Comment: Give `TransOk` and `TransAllOk` a common parent, then define a function in the parent and implement it in `TransOk` and `TransAllOk` that returns `result.company.get` or `result.companies.get` respectively. This will allow you to write a function that takes he message to send to `secCompanyActor` and can generically do the necessary processing.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner is this a pattern in Scala? Does it have a name?

Comment: It's subtype polymorphism. It's a pattern in every OO language.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I'm trying to implement this by myself, but it's really hard for me to think about what to do. Is it possible that you can write a sketch as an answer? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single method to handle this if you exploit subtype polymorphism:

First, let's give all of the response messages a common parent, and likewise for request messages:

```
abstract class SecCompanyActorResponse
case class SecCompanyActorError(error: String) extends SecCompanyActorResponse
abstract class SecCompanyActorSuccess(result: Any) extends SecCompanyActorResponse
case class TransOk(company: Company.Company) extends SecCompanyActorResponse(company)
case class TransAllOk(companies: List[Company.Company]) extends SecCompanyActorResponse(companies)

abstract class SecCompanyActorRequest[T]
case object WebGetOneCompany extends SecCompanyActorRequest[Company.Company]
case object CasperGetAllCompanies extends SecCompanyActorRequest[List[Company.Company]]
```

Then we can write:

```
def querySecCompanyActor[T](message: SecCompanyActorRequest[T]): Either[String, T] = {
  secCompanyActor ? message map {
    case SecCompanyActorError(error) => Left(error)
    case success: SecCompanyActorSuccess => Right(success.result.asInstanceOf[T])
  }
}
```

Comment: I could never imagine the code looking like this. Wow! THANK YOU.